# Programmatic filter trigger on antd tables

Tags: antd

Is there a way to programmatically trigger filtering on Antd Table Columns?

I'm building a custom Header which is a standalone styled component (So, I set the prop `showHeader={ false }` on the table and use my custom header to communicate with the table by setting states). 
I want to be able to use it to trigger filtering on the table columns. 
For sorting, I can pass a value to the `sortOrder` prop and trigger the sorter function externally. For filtering however, I don't have any obvious way to trigger the filter function.

```
{
    title: 'Title',
    dataIndex: 'title',
    width: '40%',
    key: 'title',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title),
    sortOrder: { this.state.columns['title'].sortOrder }
},
{
    title: 'Type',
    dataIndex: 'operation',
    key: 'defectType',
    width: '10%',
    filters: Object.keys(topicType).map(key => ({ text: topicType[key], value: key })),
    onFilter: (value, record) => String(value) === record.defectType
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Just managed to get this figured. 
If you want to explicitly filter your items on a table and manage the filter state on your own; you need to pass the `filteredValue` prop on the column configuration.

Setting this to null renders the whole list without filtering.

Comment: Can you please post your answer as I am also dealing with same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sanjay Could you please let me know from where you will get `topicType` in the filters section